# Remove sale signs from site in branded?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I recently developed a Wordpress site, it's developed with Woocommerce plugin. [Here](http://watchedge.com/) is my site link.

It's showing sale sign top of the every brand. How to remove it?

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding some css to your theme's style.css file:

```
.onsale { display: none !important; }
```

If you're using a pre-built theme, it's wise to do this in a child theme's style.css, as the change won't be overwritten if you update your theme.

Further reading: https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Comment: i have using captiva theme